# Python - Remove nested lists in dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have a dict named `results`.

the dict is structured in this format:

```
{'a': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']], 'b': [['2', '2', '4'],['2', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '4']], 'c': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']]}
```

I wish to remove the duplicate nested lists for each key, therefore leaving the dict with:

```
{'a': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2']], 'b': [['2', '2', '4'],['2', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '4']], 'c': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2']]}
```

I have tried:

```
newdict = {}
for k, v in results.items():
    for i in v:
        if i not in i:
            newdict[k] = i
```

any help? thanks in advance!

Comment: `if i not in i` are you _sure_ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is wrong beyond repair (sorry), mostly because of those 2 lines:

```
 if i not in i:  # makes no sense testing if something is inside itself
      newdict[k] = i   # overwrites the key with one list
```

You'd have to *count* each list, and only keep one occurrence of each.

If order doesn't matter you could do that with a nested dict/set/list comprehension.

```
results = {'a': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']], 'b': [['2', '2', '4'],['2', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '4']], 'c': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']]}

newdict = {k:[list(y) for y in {tuple(x) for x in v}] for k,v in results.items()}

print(newdict)
```

result:

```
{'a': [['1', '2', '2'], ['1', '2', '4']], 'b': [['2', '2', '4'], ['1', '2', '4'], ['2', '2', '2']], 'c': [['1', '2', '2'], ['1', '2', '4']]}
```

using a `set` allows to keep unicity, but you cannot put a `list` in a `set`, so the expression converts to `tuple` first (which is hashable), and converts back to `list` once the processing is done.

Comment: Thanks! whats the best way to count the length of all nested lists? So, for the result above, the len would be 7? Thanks

Comment: `sum(len(v) for v in newdict.values())` should do it

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of ignoring the first value and seeing if the next two are the same within the nested lists?

Comment: yes with some slicing `tuple(x[1:])`. But please don't ask too many follow-up questions in comments. This question is answered, now if you have a new question, craft another one carefully and post it (you can link to this question if you want)

Answer (score 1):

In case if order is *important*, you can use something like this:

```
results = {'a': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']],
           'b': [['2', '2', '4'],['2', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '4']],
           'c': [['1', '2', '4'],['1', '2', '2'],['1', '2', '2']]}

print({k: [y for x, y in enumerate(v) \
     if y not in v[:x]] for k, v in results.items()})
```

**Output**:

```
 {'a': [['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '2', '2']], 
  'b': [['2', '2', '4'], ['2', '2', '2'], ['1', '2', '4']], 
  'c': [['1', '2', '4'], ['1', '2', '2']]}
```

To skip first sub-list and require checking only in the remaining, you could do:

```
print({k: [y for x, y in enumerate(v) \
     if y not in v[1:x]] for k, v in results.items()})
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way of ignoring the first value and seeing if the next two are the same within the nested lists?